# How to disable user interaction in FSCalender swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

I am using fscalendar library to show some activity saved in the calendar and I am done with showing activity on the calendar, but I don't want any circle on the current date and I also want to disable user interaction. Is there any way to do so. Anybody has some idea please help me out.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want *any* user interaction? Not even scrolling? Do you mean you just want to disable selection? And what do you mean by "selected as normal"? By default, the current date is not selected, just shown with a different color. And when it is selected, the default appearance of it looks just like any other selected date. So given all that, what do you want to do with the current date?

Comment: Yes I want to disable user interaction any date should not be selected, and don't want any circle on current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set `today` and `allowsSelection`, since selection, as far as I know, is the only other interaction you can have with the calendar other than scrolling.

```
calendar.today = nil // makes today appear just like any other date
calendar.allowsSelection = false
```